Neovim BiomeJS not using biome.json formatting
My lsp.lua is as follows:
local util = require("lspconfig.util")

return {
  {
    "williamboman/mason.nvim",
    opts = function(_, opts)
      vim.list_extend(opts.ensure_installed, {
        "biome",
        "stylua",
        "selene",
        "luacheck",
        "shellcheck",
        "shfmt",
        "tailwindcss-language-server",
        "typescript-language-server",
        "css-lsp",
      })
    end,
  },
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    opts = {
      --- other options
      servers = {
        tsserver = {
          on_attach = function(client)
            client.server_capabilities.documentFormattingProvider = false
          end,
        },
        biome = {
          cmd = { "biome", "lsp-proxy" },
          filetypes = {
            "javascript",
            "javascriptreact",
            "json",
            "jsonc",
            "typescript",
            "typescript.tsx",
            "typescriptreact",
            "astro",
            "svelte",
            "vue",
            "css",
          },
          root_dir = util.root_pattern("biome.json"),
        },
      },
    },
  },
}

So in my project, I have a biome.json which I have configured to follow the formatting and linting we are using in our project (we migrated from eslint and prettier). This seems to work fine for my fellow colleagues who are using VSCode. For me, however, I use neovim in my daily work, so I can't seem to make it follow biome.json configuration and hence resulting in different formatting everytime I save a file. What is it I'm missing here?
